# Surfing web anonymously on a mac using Firefox SSH and Tor

Tags: ssh, tor, firefox

I want to download and upload to the internet anonymously. I have successfully configured Forefox to access internet through a secure SSH tunnel service (and remote server). I use 'SSH Tunnel Manager' app to do this (like PuTty for Windows).I also access the Tor network using the Tor Browser Bundle. But I can't figure out how to essentially chain the two together so that Firefox -> SSH server -> Tor -> web and then return back to Firefox. Since I'm only interested in anonymizing web/browser traffic I could use Privoxy (or FreeCap) to socksify SSH Tunnel Manager and maybe integrate a download manager into this mix. I've tried a number of different configurations but have not been successful. What am I missing? I can use 'Terminal' to do a command line configuration. Or preferably an explanation of how to configure Firefox, Tor Browser and SSH Tunnel Manager to allow this traffic route.

Answer (score 0):

If you want "Firefox -> SSH server -> Tor -> web", you need to start a SOCKS5 proxy through your SSH server, and then tell Tor to connect through that. How to do that is described [here](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Tunnel_Tor_through_proxy_or_VPN_or_SSH).

SSH connections aren't very stable long term, however. A far more reliable approach involves running Whonix connecting through a VPN on the host machine.